# access a child class method from another child

Tags: php, inheritance, validation

I am using my own light weight MVC framework. I have a main model with two child classes, members_model and validation model.

```
Members_Model extends Model
Validation_Model extends Model
```

In the members_model I need to validate some data. How do I call a validation method from Members Model? Thanks for any help, I have searched and have no solution.

EDIT: TO make it more simple, I need Child A to play with Child B's toy.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to instantiate a validation model and use its methods. But I think your design is flawed. See the question: **[How should a Model be constructed in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863870/871050)**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to access a parent method http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

then child A must instanciate a child B and access it`s method or make a static method in B so you do not need to instanciate B

Comment: I need child A to access one of Child B's toys? Does  that explain better?